# How to convert enum to a bool for DataBinding in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Is it possible to do this? I need to use:

```
this.ControlName.DataBindings.Add (...)
```

so I can't define logic other than bind my `enum` value to a `bool`.

For example:

```
(DataClass) Data.Type (enum)
```

EDIT:

I need to bind `Data.Type` which is an enum to a checkbox's `Checked` property. So if the `Data.Type` is `Secure`, I want the `SecureCheckbox` to be checked, through data binding.

Comment: Maybe you could be a little more specific about what you want to bind to what? CheckBox to an int column? Enum to a Bit column?

Comment: Sorry I added more detail now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Winforms binding generates two important and useful events: `Format` and `Parse`.

The format event fires when pulling data from a source into a control and the Parse event fires when pulling data from a control back into the data source.

If you handle these events you can alter/retype the values going back and forth during binding.

For example here are a couple of example handlers for these events:

```
 public static void StringValuetoEnum<T>(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
 {
      T type = default(T);
      if (cevent.DesiredType != type.GetType()) return;
      cevent.Value = Enum.Parse(type.GetType(), cevent.Value.ToString());
 }

 public static void EnumToStringValue<T>(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
 {
      //if (cevent.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;
      cevent.Value = ((int)cevent.Value).ToString();
 }
```

And here is some code attaching these event handlers:

```
 List<NameValuePair> bts = EnumHelper.EnumToNameValuePairList<LegalEntityType>(true, null);
 this.cboIncType.DataSource = bts;                
 this.cboIncType.DisplayMember = "Name";
 this.cboIncType.ValueMember = "Value";

 Binding a = new Binding("SelectedValue", this.ActiveCustomer.Classification.BusinessType, "LegalEntityType");
 a.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(ControlValueFormatter.EnumToStringValue<LegalEntityType>);
 a.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(ControlValueFormatter.StringValuetoEnum<LegalEntityType>);
 this.cboIncType.DataBindings.Add(a);
```

So in your case you can just create a SecEnum to Bool handler for the format event and within that do something like:

```
 SecEnum se = Enum.Parse(typeof(SecEnum), cevent.Value.ToString());
 cevent.Value = (bool)(se== SecEnum.Secure);
```

and then reverse that during parse.

Comment: `Type type = typeof(T);` works also with generic type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are binding to your class you could always have a property on it like this:

```
public bool IsSecured
{
   get 
   {
      if (myEnum == SecEnum.Secured)
         return true;
      else 
         return false;
   }
}
```

Just reverse for the setter if needed.

Comment: return (myEnum == SecEnum.Secured);

Comment: Thanks I did a similar one with INotifyPropertyChanged but it didn't work. Because I was changing the Data itself, the IsProperty wasn't signaled. I tried doing it myself, but that didn't help either.