# Bind multiple datatable columns to one multiline textbox

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, datatable, datatables

I am trying to bind a text box to a datatable that contains one row. But I want the textbox to be bound to the concatenation of 4 columns.

I am not sure if it possible without doing it during the binding.

This following one works fine, but I want also "SHIP_ADDRESS1" to be concatenated to my multiline textbox.

```
shipToTextbox.DataBindings.Add("Text",dataTbl, "SHIP_TO");
```

Is there a way to do it during the binding?

EDITED:

I added an extension method to the DataTable as following:

```
public static DataTable Concatenates(this DataTable datatable, string columnName, params string[] columns)
    {
        var column = new DataColumn(columnName, typeof(String));
        datatable.Columns.Add(column);

        var concatenation = string.Empty;

        foreach (var c in columns)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(concatenation))
            {
                concatenation = datatable.Rows[0][c].ToString().Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                concatenation = concatenation + Environment.NewLine + datatable.Rows[0][c].ToString().Trim();
            }
        }

        datatable.Rows[0][column] = concatenation;

        return datatable;
    }
```

and I am calling it as following:

```
shipToTextbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt.Concatenates("SHIP", "SHIP_TO", "SHIP_ADDRESS1", "SHIP_ADDRESS2", "SHIP_ADDRESS3"), "SHIP");
```

Is it an acceptable solution? Is there a way using LINQ to write Concatenate extension method in a better way?

Comment: If possible, create a custom public property which will return concatenated string. Then bind with that property.

Comment: Can't you add a computed column to the table which contains this expression: `col.Expression="SHIP_TO - SHIP_ADDRESS1 - SHIP_ADDRESS2 ..."
`?

Comment: The data is coming from a View used by multiple applications and I don't want to change it. In this case I presume that I will have to do it at DataTable level

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about xaml frameworks, you can MultiValueConverters and ValueConverters.

However winforms binding generates two important and useful events: Format and Parse.

The format event fires when pulling data from a source into a control and the Parse event fires when pulling data from a control back into the data source. If you handle these events you can alter/retype the values going back and forth during binding.

Comment: I cannot see any format event on the textbox events list. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @asad mehmood - you've just done a copy & paste of the answer from here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2044067/how-to-convert-enum-to-a-bool-for-databinding-in-winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044067/how-to-convert-enum-to-a-bool-for-databinding-in-winforms)